# Spring Transactional not working rollback

Tags: spring, hibernate, jta, transactional

I created maven mvc project with Hibernate 4.3.11, Springframework 4
I have made a project without xml configuration, and when I test transactional rollback it write into table, even exception was happend

I do not know why is it happend. Please help...

Here is my project [a link](http://www.mfp.co.rs/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/SpringHibernateTransactionalExample.zip) for download and help.

And here are my config params and other files.
HibernateConfiguration.java

```
package rs.co.mytest.configuration;


@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan({ "rs.co" })
@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:application.properties" })
public class HibernateConfiguration {

@Autowired
private Environment environment;

@Bean
public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
    LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
    sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "rs.co" });
    sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
    return sessionFactory;
 }

@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.driverClassName"));
    dataSource.setUrl(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.url"));
    dataSource.setUsername(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.username"));
    dataSource.setPassword(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.password"));
    return dataSource;
}

private Properties hibernateProperties() {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("hibernate.dialect", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
    properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
    properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.format_sql"));
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create-drop");
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect");
   return properties;        
}

@Bean
@Autowired
public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory s) {
   HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
   txManager.setSessionFactory(s);
   return txManager;
     }

  }
```

AppInitializer.java

```
        public class AppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { ApplicationContextConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext appContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        appContext.register(ApplicationContextConfig.class);
        appContext.register(HibernateConfiguration.class);

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet(
                "SpringDispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(appContext));
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.addMapping("/");

       }

      } 


DAO Interface and Object 
     @Repository
     public interface MyTableDao {

    public MyTableModel addMyTable(MyTableModel model) throws Exception;
    public void deleteMyTable(Integer id) throws Exception;
    public List<MyTableBean> listMyTable();

    public MyTableModel getMyTable(Integer id);
    public MyTableBean findMyTable(String naziv);


     }


     @Repository("MyTableDao")
     @Transactional
     public class MyTableDaoImpl implements MyTableDao {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    private String sqlBean = " select new rs.co.wog.sifrarnik.bean.MyTableBean(" 
            + " t.idMyTable as idMyTable, "
            + " t.naziv as naziv "
            + " )"
            ;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<MyTableBean> listMyTable() {

        List<MyTableBean> bean;

        String sql = sqlBean 
                 + " from MyTableModel t "
                 + " order by naziv ";
        Query query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(sql);

        bean = (List<MyTableBean>) query.list();

        return bean;
    }




    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = false, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor = Exception.class)
    public MyTableModel addMyTable(MyTableModel ulazModel) throws Exception{
        MyTableModel model = null;
        Session sess = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction tx = null;
        try{    
                tx = sess.beginTransaction();
                if (null == ulazModel.getIdgrupa_artikla()){
                    model = ulazModel;
                    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(model);
//Here I made Exception, but rollback did not happend using transactional

                    if (model.getIdgrupa_artikla() != null)
                        throw new Exception("My exception");
                } else {
                    model = getMyTable(ulazModel.getIdgrupa_artikla());
                    model.azurirajModel(ulazModel);

                    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(model);
                }   
                tx.commit();
            }        
         catch (Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
             if (tx!=null) tx.rollback();
             throw e;
         }
         finally {
             sess.close();
         }

        return model;



    }

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = false, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor = Exception.class)
    public void deleteMyTable(Integer idMyTable) {
        sessionFactory
                .getCurrentSession()
                .createQuery(
                        "DELETE FROM MyTableModel WHERE idMyTable =:idMyTable "
                                )
                    .setInteger("idMyTable", idMyTable)
                    .executeUpdate();
    }


    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor = Exception.class)
    public MyTableModel getMyTable(Integer idMyTable) {
        if ((idMyTable == null ))
            return null;

        MyTableModel tmpMyTable = null;

        String sql = 
                 " from MyTableModel "
                + " where idMyTable = :idMyTable ";
        try {

            tmpMyTable = (MyTableModel) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
                    .createQuery(sql)
                    .setInteger("idMyTable", idMyTable)
                    .uniqueResult();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return tmpMyTable;

    }

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor = Exception.class)
    public MyTableBean findMyTable(String naziv) {
        if (naziv == null)
            return null;

        MyTableBean tmpMyTable = null;

        String sql = sqlBean 
                 + " from MyTableModel t "
                 + " where t.naziv = :naziv ";
        try {
            tmpMyTable = (MyTableBean) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
                    .createQuery(sql)
                    .setString("naziv", naziv)
                    .uniqueResult();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return tmpMyTable;

     }

     }
```

Service  interface and object

```
public interface MyTableService {

public MyTableBean addMyTable(MyTableBean bean) throws Exception ;
public void deleteMyTable(Integer IdMyTable)  throws Exception ;
public List<MyTableBean> listMyTable();

public MyTableBean getMyTable(Integer IdMyTable);
public MyTableBean findMyTable(String naziv);



 }


 @Service("MyTable")
 @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.SUPPORTS, readOnly = true)
 public class MyTableServiceImpl implements MyTableService{
@Autowired
private MyTableDao MyTableDao;

@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly = false)
public MyTableBean addMyTable(MyTableBean bean) throws Exception {
    MyTableModel model = new MyTableModel(bean);
    return new MyTableBean(MyTableDao.addMyTable(model));
}

public void deleteMyTable(Integer Iduser) throws Exception {
    MyTableDao.deleteMyTable(Iduser);
}

@Override
public List<MyTableBean> listMyTable() {
    return MyTableDao.listMyTable();
}

@Override
public MyTableBean getMyTable(Integer id) {
    MyTableModel model = MyTableDao.getMyTable(id);
    if (null == model)
        return null;
    return new MyTableBean(model);
}

@Override
public MyTableBean findMyTable(String username) {
    return MyTableDao.findMyTable(username);
}   


 }
```

Controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class AppController {

    @Autowired
    private MyTableService MyTableService;

    @Autowired 
    private MyTableValidator MyTableValidator;


    @ModelAttribute("locale")
    public Locale locale(ModelAndView model ){
        Locale l = new Locale("en_US");
        model.addObject("locale",  l );
        return l;
    }   

    // ////////////////// ovaj init binder je vezan za metodu save
    @InitBinder
    public void registerDateBinder(WebDataBinder binder, 
            Locale locale) {
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new CustomDateEditor(
                dateFormat, true));
        DecimalFormat df =new DecimalFormat();
        DecimalFormatSymbols dfs = new DecimalFormatSymbols(locale);
        /****************************************************************************/
        df.setGroupingUsed(true);
        df.setDecimalFormatSymbols(dfs);
        df.setMaximumFractionDigits(32);
        df.setMaximumIntegerDigits(32);
        binder.registerCustomEditor(BigDecimal.class, new CustomNumberEditor(BigDecimal.class,df, true));       
    }


        @ExceptionHandler(IOException.class)
        public ModelAndView handleIOException(IOException ex) {
            ModelAndView model1 = new ModelAndView(new RedirectView("/"));//
            return model1;
        }
        @ModelAttribute("isarchive") 
        public Boolean isarchive(ModelAndView model ){
            Boolean isarchive = false;
            model.addObject("isarchive", isarchive);
            return isarchive;
        }


    /**
     * Simply selects the home view to render by returning its name.
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = {"", "/index"}, method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "text/plain;charset=UTF-8")
    public ModelAndView index(Locale locale,  Principal principal,
            HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {


        MyTableBean formBean = new MyTableBean();
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("index","myTableBean", formBean);//


        Date date = new Date();
        DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.LONG, DateFormat.LONG, locale);

        String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(date);

        model.addObject("serverTime", formattedDate );
        model.addObject(locale);

        return model;
    }


    @RequestMapping(value = "/deleteMyTable", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "text/plain;charset=UTF-8")
    public @ResponseBody
    String deleteMyTablea(@RequestParam Integer idMyTable) {
        String rezultat = " Obrisano  " + String.valueOf(idMyTable);
        try {
            MyTableService.deleteMyTable(idMyTable);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            rezultat = "Nije obrisana ";
        }
        return rezultat;
    }


        @RequestMapping(value = "saveMyTable", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "text/plain;charset=UTF-8")
        public @ResponseBody
        ModelAndView  processSubmit(
                @Valid MyTableBean formBean,
                BindingResult result,
                Locale locale) {

            MyTableValidator.validate(formBean, result);
            if (result.hasErrors()) {
                ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("index","myTableBean", formBean);//

                model.addObject("idgrupa_artikla", formBean.getIdgrupa_artikla());

                return model;//"MyTableForm";
            }


        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView(new RedirectView("index"));//

            try {
                    MyTableService.addMyTable(formBean);
            } catch(Exception e){
                   model = new ModelAndView("Greska");//
                   model.addObject("locale", locale);
                   model.addObject("greska_knjizenja", e.toString());
                   e.printStackTrace();
                   return model;
            } finally {

            }

        model.addObject(locale);

        return model;

    }




     }
```

and pom.xml

```
     <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0  http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
       <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
       <groupId>rs.co</groupId>
     <artifactId>SpringHibernateTransactionalExample</artifactId>
     <packaging>war</packaging>
     <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
     <name>SpringHibernateTransactionalExample Maven Webapp</name>
     <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>



    <properties>
        <springframework.version>4.2.4.RELEASE</springframework.version>
        <springsecurity.version>4.0.4.RELEASE</springsecurity.version>
        <hibernate.version>4.3.11.Final</hibernate.version>
        <mysql.connector.version>5.1.35</mysql.connector.version>


        <apache.tiles>3.0.5</apache.tiles>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <mail.version>1.4.7</mail.version>
        <com.fasterxml.jackson.core>2.5.0</com.fasterxml.jackson.core>
        <org.codehaus.jackson>1.9.13</org.codehaus.jackson>


     <org.aspectj-version>1.8.5</org.aspectj-version>
        </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
     <dependency>
       <groupId>org.beangle.webmvc</groupId>
      <artifactId>beangle-webmvc-core_2.11</artifactId>
      <version>0.3.0</version>
     </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${springsecurity.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${springsecurity.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
            <version>${springsecurity.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>${mysql.connector.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
            <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0a</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.1.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
     <dependency>
         <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
         <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
         <version>1.3.1</version>
     </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
         <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
         <version>2.4</version>
     </dependency>

     <dependency>
         <groupId>org.jfree</groupId>
         <artifactId>jfreechart</artifactId>
         <version>1.0.19</version>
     </dependency>

     <dependency>
         <groupId>org.jfree</groupId>
         <artifactId>jcommon</artifactId>
         <version>1.0.23</version>
     </dependency>
      <dependency>
       <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
       <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
       <version>2.7</version>
     </dependency>  
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5</version>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>${com.fasterxml.jackson.core}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>${com.fasterxml.jackson.core}</version>
    </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>${com.fasterxml.jackson.core}</version>
        </dependency>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
            <version>${org.codehaus.jackson}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>${org.codehaus.jackson}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core-lgpl</artifactId>
            <version>${org.codehaus.jackson}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-lgpl</artifactId>
            <version>${org.codehaus.jackson}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.8</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-convention-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.8</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-json-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-core</artifactId>
            <version>${apache.tiles}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-template</artifactId>
            <version>${apache.tiles}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-jsp</artifactId>
            <version>${apache.tiles}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>${apache.tiles}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
     <dependency>
       <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
       <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
       <version>2.6</version>
       <type>pom</type>
     </dependency>
       <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
       </dependency>        
       <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-web</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
  </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-taglib</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-to-slf4j</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
  </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.mobile</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-mobile-device</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ws-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.0.RELEASE</version>
     </dependency>  
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.6.Final</version>
    </dependency>

     <!--  kraj jpa persistance -->    

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.3</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.8</source>
                        <target>1.8</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.6</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <warSourceDirectory>src/main/webapp</warSourceDirectory>
                                <warName>SpringHibernateTransactionalExample</warName>
                        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <finalName>SpringHibernateExample</finalName>
    </build>
     </project>
```

Comment: Are you using InnoDB for the table in mysql?

Comment: MyISAM. It seems that rollback not working on it!

Comment: Yes, that is the problem.I have the same problem with xml configuration, and I forgot. Thanks.

Comment: Exactly... MyISAM doesn't support transactions.

Answer (score 1):

As we discussed in the comments you are using MyISAM as the storage engine behind your table. Please consider using something else (InnoDB preferred) because MyISAM doesn't support transactions.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/myisam-storage-engine.html